# Connect a Mac to VPN via SSTP without routing internet traffic

Tags: macos, vpn, macos-mojave, sstp

I have a Mac running MacOS Mojave. I need to connect to my work's VPN via SSTP so can't do it with the OS' default software.
I have found iSSTP and am currently using that and can connect (although it's slow).

My issue is that the internet traffic from my Mac must be trying to go over the VPN as well as when I'm connected I lose internet from my Mac. If I remote into my work's PC after setting up the VPN that does have internet access.

SO I'm trying to find out how to prevent iSSTP from trying to route internet traffic over the VPN.

I'm happy to try another application to setup the VPN if someone knows of a better one that DOES let you setup this kind of connection.

My current iSSTP "Advanced Options" are the default:

```
usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 refuse-eap noauth noipdefault defaultroute
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove the *defaultroute* keyword at the end it will not add a remote router as default gateway.

To display routes run netstat -rn

To add routes automatically, create /etc/ppp/ip-up using sudo.

It should look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ route add -net <netaddress> -interface ppp0
```

for every network address. Network address can be something like 192.168.1.0